# How can I use NSLog in main() but outside of NSApplicationMain?

Tags: cocoa, logging

I have read [questions/559482/why-doesnt-an-iphone-apps-main-function-ever-get-a-chance-to-finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559482/why-doesnt-an-iphone-apps-main-function-ever-get-a-chance-to-finish), which explains why `NSApplicationMain` never actually returns. The same thing happens (for the same reason) in a desktop cocoa application, which is what I am working on.

With that in mind, **how would I go about using `NSLog` to output some final debugging messages when my application exits?**

To be specific, I would like to do something like this:

```
int myDebugVariable = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CMLog(@"application begin");

    int exitCode = NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);

    CMLog(@"application end. Debugging variable = %d", myDebugVariable);

    [pool release];
    return exitCode;
}
```

In this example, The "application begin" line is printed to the console, but the "application end." line is not.

**Note #1:** In my actual code, I am using something more sophisticated than `myDebugVariable`. This is a simplified example that illustrates the effect I am trying to achieve.

**Note #2:** I am familiar with the `ApplicationWillTerminate` method, which gets called when the application is about to quit, but it does not suit my needs. My debugging code relies on the `dealloc` methods for some custom classes, so it does not come into play until after `ApplicationWillTerminate` is called.

---

**update:**

[Adam Rosenfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016093/how-can-i-use-nslog-in-main-but-outside-of-nsapplicationmain/1016110#1016110) did the trick. For the sake of completeness, here is a working solution:

```
int myDebugVariable = 0;

void my_exit_handler(void)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CMLog(@"application end: Debugging variable = %d", myDebugVariable);

    [pool release];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CMLog(@"application begin");
    atexit(my_exit_handler);

    int exitCode = NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);

    [pool release];
    return exitCode;
}
```

Comment: If you don't use an NSLog derivative/Foundation classes in your exit handler, you won't need to create an autorelease pool. Also, don't forget that some classes will never be deallocated/released, even at termination.

Comment: @Jason Coco: Good point. I had already discovered that some classes were not released, but it bears mentioning here. As for the autorelease pool, I suppose printf would work, but I've gotten used to to NSLog and NSString, so I may as well use them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`atexit(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) to register an exit handler.  It will automatically be invoked when your app exits, either by finishing main or by calling `exit(3)`.  For example:

```
void my_exit_handler(void)
{
    NSLog(@"about to exit, x = %d\n", x);
}

// at some point during app initialization...
atexit(&my_exit_handler);
```

Comment: I had to add another NSAutoreleasePool in my_exit_handler for this to work, but it definitely did the trick. Thank you!